# Input form using FormLayout in swt

Tags: java, layout, button, swt, textfield

i am new to swt and im trying to create a layout in a window. Each texfield will have a label to the left of the textfield- however in some cases there may be two textfields per label, and maybe at a later date there will be radio buttons added. Is a formlayout the best way of doing this? It seems to me unnecessarily over-complicated. I dont have windowbuilder or a visual designer utility and am finding the FormAttachment method difficult to handle. Any advice appreciated. I have attached a screenshot of the basic gui design Im trying to create.

Unfortunately im not allowed upload images for the moment, as i a new user. Essentially the structure i am aiming for is like so:

```
LABEL TEXTBOX
LABEL TEXTBOX TEXTBOX
LABEL TEXTBOX
LABEL TEXTBOX TEXTBOX
LABEL CALENDAR CONTROL
     OK  |  NOK
```

Comment: I don't see any screenshot. BTW: If your previous question is solved, please accept one of the answers or create your own answer.

Comment: Hi Baz, unfortunately im not allowed upload images for the moment, as i a new user. Essentially the structure i am aiming for is like so:

Comment: Read this article (especially the part about `GridLayout`): [Understanding Layouts in SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html)

Comment: Thanks baz, ive already read this- but i thought that considering the layout im using is a classical form the formlayout would be more appropriate?

Comment: is there a way to make the gridlayout see two components as one?

Comment: Using a `FormLayout` without the WindowBuilder will be a very hard task... However, i think using a `FormLayout` in your case will be a good choice. So, you should install the WB using Help > Install New Software. Update site could be found [here](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php)

Comment: @BrianFeran Yes, you can use `GridData` for the component that should span two columns and set `horizontalSpan = 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example that should explain how to span a widget across multiple columns of a `GridLayout`:

```
public class StackOverflow2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("StackOverflow");
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));

        Label firstLabel = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        firstLabel.setText("Label");
        Text firstText   = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        addSpanData(firstText, 2);

        Label secondLabel = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        secondLabel.setText("Label");
        Text secondText   = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        addSpanData(secondText, 1);

        Text thirdText    = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        addSpanData(thirdText, 1);

        Label thirdLabel = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        thirdLabel.setText("Label");

        Text fourthText  = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        addSpanData(fourthText, 2);

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    private static void addSpanData(Control comp, int span)
    {
        GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false);
        data.horizontalSpan = span;
        comp.setLayoutData(data);
    }
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image]